# How to make Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView window resizeable in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, webview, resizable

How to make web view window re-sizable.Here is the xaml code,

- WebView.xaml

  ```
   <UserControl xmlns:WebViewControls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"> 
   <StackPanel Height="704" Width="1309">
      <WebViewControls:WebView Name="webViewConfiguration"  Height="500" Width="879" />
  </StackPanel>
  </UserControl>
  ```
- WebView.xaml.cs

  ```
   webViewConfiguration.Navigate(AppConfigURL);//some url
  ```

The issue here is webview window renders with the given width and height , irrespective of screen size.In larger screen's or monitors webview window appears to be smaller and in smaller screens it appears to be large.Is there a way to dynamically render it using screen size or a way to resize it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to get rid of the `StackPanel` to begin with. Why do you set a fixed height and width if you want the control to be resizable?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Removing them doesn't make it re-sizable.

Comment: The parent window is resizable and the contents in it should adopt to the size assuming you use the appropriate layout panels. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: WebView control doesn't appear at the correct scale when users move the host application between monitors that have different screen resolutions. Please refer below https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview-known-issues.  I am looking for a work around for this?. Did you tried using webview? @mm8